# Why the getFont() method can't be called and give out NullPointerException.

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts, awt

/*My objective is to make listener objects to this GUI so that whenever there is a change in the font style or font family selected, or the "OK" button is pressed, then the full name of the font is displayed in the text field. Thank you in advance.*/

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Component.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class QuestionTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckRadio two = new CheckRadio("Font Chooser");
        two.init();

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CheckRadio extends JFrame {


    public CheckRadio(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public void init() {

        JPanel check = new JPanel();
        check.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));


        check.add(new JCheckBox("Bold"));
        check.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD)); //getFont() method can be found through out the code`enter code here. Bottom down at the Listener method I also did create a getFont() method for those listener.
        check.add(new JCheckBox("Italic"));
        check.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));

        JPanel radio = new JPanel();
        radio.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        JRadioButton ti = new JRadioButton("Times");
        JRadioButton he = new JRadioButton("Heltivica");
        JRadioButton co = new JRadioButton("Courier");
        ti.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,15));
        he.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,16));
        co.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,17));
        group.add(ti);
        group.add(he);
        group.add(co);

        radio.add(ti);
        radio.add(he);
        radio.add(co);

        JLabel textBox = new JLabel();
        textBox.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        textBox.add(new JLabel(""));
        textBox.add(new JTextField(10));
        textBox.add(new JLabel(""));

        JLabel okButton = new JLabel();
        okButton.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        okButton.add(new JLabel(""));
        okButton.add(new JButton("OK"));
        okButton.add(new JLabel(""));

        Container panel = this.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        panel.add(check);
        panel.add(radio);
        panel.add(textBox);
        panel.add(okButton);

        ti.addActionListener(new TimesListener(textBox));
        he.addActionListener(new HelvticaListener(textBox));
        co.addActionListener(new CourierListener(textBox));

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class TimesListener implements ActionListener {

    // JLabel okButton;
    JButton okButton;
    JRadioButton ti;
    JCheckBox bo, it;
    JLabel textBox;
    Font f;

    public TimesListener(JLabel textBox) {
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }

    public TimesListener(JButton okButton, JRadioButton ti, JCheckBox bo,
            JCheckBox it, JLabel textBox) {
        this.okButton = okButton;
        this.ti = ti;
        this.bo = bo;
        this.it = it;
        this.textBox = textBox;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == okButton) {
            if (ti.isSelected()) {
                if (bo.isSelected()) {
                    if (it.isSelected()) {
                        textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                                Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC,
                                15));
                        textBox.setText("Times");
                    } else {
                        textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                                Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.BOLD, 15));
                        textBox.setText("Times");
                    }
                } else if (it.isSelected()) {
                    textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                            Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.ITALIC, 15));
                    textBox.setText("Times");
                } else {
                    textBox.setFont(getFont()
                            .deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 15));
                    textBox.setText("Times");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private Font getFont() {
        return null;
    }
}

class HelvticaListener implements ActionListener {

    JButton okButton;
    JRadioButton he;
    JCheckBox bo, it;
    JLabel textBox;
    Font f;

    public HelvticaListener(JLabel textBox) {
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }

    public HelvticaListener(JButton okButton, JRadioButton he, JCheckBox bo,
            JCheckBox it, JLabel textBox) {
        this.okButton = okButton;
        this.he = he;
        this.bo = bo;
        this.it = it;
        this.textBox = textBox;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == okButton) {
            if (he.isSelected()) {
                if (bo.isSelected()) {
                    if (it.isSelected()) {
                        textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                                Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC,
                                16));
                        textBox.setText("Helvtica");
                    } else {
                        textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                                Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.BOLD, 16));
                        textBox.setText("Helvtica");
                    }
                } else if (it.isSelected()) {
                    textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                            Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.ITALIC, 16));
                    textBox.setText("Helvtica");
                } else {
                    textBox.setFont(getFont()
                            .deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 16));
                    textBox.setText("Helvtica");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private Font getFont() {
        return null;
    }
}

class CourierListener implements ActionListener {

    // JLabel okButton;
    JButton okButton;
    JRadioButton co;
    JCheckBox bo, it;
    JLabel textBox;
    Font f;

    public CourierListener(JLabel textBox) {
        this.textBox = textBox;
    }

    public CourierListener(JButton okButton, JRadioButton co, JCheckBox bo,
            JCheckBox it, JLabel textBox) {
        this.okButton = okButton;
        this.co = co;
        this.bo = bo;
        this.it = it;
        this.textBox = textBox;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == okButton) {
            if (co.isSelected()) {
                if (bo.isSelected()) {
                    if (it.isSelected()) {
                        textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                                Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC,
                                18));
                        textBox.setText("Courier");
                    } else {
                        textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                                Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.BOLD, 18));
                        textBox.setText("Courier");
                    }
                } else if (it.isSelected()) {
                    textBox.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(
                            Font.TRUETYPE_FONT + Font.ITALIC, 18));
                    textBox.setText("Courier");
                } else {
                    textBox.setFont(getFont()
                            .deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 18));
                    textBox.setText("Courier");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Font getFont() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously? The `getFont()` method returns null. So of course dereferencing it will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: I'm a beginner, can anyone help me solve my problem, what should I do for the getFont() method? Thank you

Comment: Which line of code throws the NullPointerException (or NPE for short)?

Comment: You should write code in it that returns an object that can be dereferenced and has all the methods your code is trying to invoke on the result of `getFont()`.

Comment: `private Font getFont() { return null;  }` doesn't seem problematic to you?

Comment: For future reference if you have similar questions, `"Line 31"` tells us little of use since none of us want to count each line, one by one in your posted code, hoping that you've posted **all** the code including the package declaration and have skipped no lines. You need to post the actual line so we can search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you haven't set the `Font` in the `JFrame` so it won't return a `Font` when you call `getFont`.

Second, this can be much cleaner. You simply create an `ActionListender` soley for the button and make the variable you want to use on part of the class. There you can simply add a function to change the font.

I have done this for you because I was bored

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class QuestionTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckRadio two = new CheckRadio("Font Chooser");
        two.init();

    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class CheckRadio extends JFrame {

    JButton okButton;
    JCheckBox bold;
    JCheckBox italic;
    JRadioButton ti;
    JRadioButton he;
    JRadioButton co;
    ButtonGroup group;
    JTextField tf;

    public CheckRadio(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public void init() {

        setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        JPanel check = new JPanel();
        check.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        bold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        bold.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        italic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        italic.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));

        check.add(bold);
        check.add(italic);

        JPanel radio = new JPanel();
        radio.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        group = new ButtonGroup();

        ti = new JRadioButton("Times");
        he = new JRadioButton("Heltivica");
        co = new JRadioButton("Courier");
        ti.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 15));
        he.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 16));
        co.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 17));
        group.add(ti);
        group.add(he);
        group.add(co);

        radio.add(ti);
        radio.add(he);
        radio.add(co);

        JLabel textBox = new JLabel();
        textBox.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        tf = new JTextField(10);

        textBox.add(new JLabel(""));
        textBox.add(tf);
        textBox.add(new JLabel(""));

        JLabel okLabel = new JLabel();
        okLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        okButton = new JButton("OK");

        okLabel.add(new JLabel(""));
        okLabel.add(okButton);
        okLabel.add(new JLabel(""));

        Container panel = this.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
        panel.add(check);
        panel.add(radio);
        panel.add(textBox);
        panel.add(okLabel);

        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                updateFont();

            }
        });

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void updateFont() {
        int derivedFont = Font.TRUETYPE_FONT;
        String text = "";
        int font = 0;
        if (italic.isSelected())
            derivedFont += Font.ITALIC;
        if (bold.isSelected())
            derivedFont += Font.BOLD;
        if (ti.isSelected()){
            font = 15;
            text = "times";
        } else if (he.isSelected()){
            font = 16;
            text = "helvtica";
        } else if (co.isSelected()){
            font = 18;
            text = "courrier";
        }

        tf.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(derivedFont, font));
        tf.setText(text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Once `JFrame` is made displayable, `getFont` will return a valid value

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your explanation, this is really helpful to me :) you really made up my day.